# EventHandler {"MouseDown", 1} with PassEventsDown -> True not working as expected

Tags: dynamic, eventhandler

I want my `EventHandler` to respond only to left mouse clicks and pass the right mouse click to the built in event handler.

I have tried

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Disk[Dynamic[pt], .1]}, 
   PlotRange -> 1], {"MouseDown", 1} :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]), PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

But the problem is that the point moves even on right clicks. Is this a bug? **How can I make the point move only on left clicks and display the graphics pop up menu on right clicks (without moving)?**

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Disk[Dynamic[pt], .1]}, 
   PlotRange -> 1], {"MouseDown", 1} :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]), PassEventsDown -> False]]
```

Responds only to left clicks as expected.

So to clarify: I want to have this menu, but without the point going to the position of the right click. The point should respond to left clicks only.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm running MMA 9.0.0 on Win 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is, instead of MouseDown, "MouseClicked". MouseDown is always true, for left and right mouse button (stupid me)...

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
   EventHandler[
      Graphics[{Disk[Dynamic[pt], .1]}, PlotRange -> 1], {"MouseClicked", 1} 
            :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]), PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Ajasja DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Disk[Dynamic[pt], .1]}, 
   PlotRange -> 1], {"MouseDown", 
    1} :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]), PassEventsDown -> False]]

This does exactly what you want; at least for me. Move on left clicks and don't move on right clicks, but display popup menu...

Comment: So? What exactly is your problem then? Maybe it was too late yesterday....gosh...I don't get it.

Comment: on what platform are you and what Mma version?

Comment: so we have an identical setup and this works perfectly on mine, as you can see in my edit...

Comment: Thanks! This is much better. Although there is still something fishy going on. Try to left click multiple times and the point will move again.

Comment: Yes. True. I don't know how to capture that specific behaviour. Maybe you could sell this as a feature? ;)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps :)

Comment: You could've left my queer beginnings ;) eventually part of my own hubris :)

Comment: If you really want to, you can revert the edit. But I think this is much clearer.